Error with "readfis" in Octave GNU Fuzzy logic toolbox
I got the following error reading the FIS I already created:

fis = readfis ( 'dc_motor.fis')
error: line_vec(5): out of bound 4 (dimensions are 1x4)
error: called from
readfis>get_next_rule at line 519 column 23
readfis>read_rules at line 346 column 27
readfis at line 92 column 7



This FIS for a permanent magnet DC motor control by voltage.
This is my first attempt to use this octave toolbox and the application, so I am scratching the surface.
My question is basically  where to locate the code  generated for Octave fuzzy locic so I can
get mor info regarding the error exsposed avobe.
The following is the FIS  I am trying to read  throug the sentence : fis = readfis ('dc_motor.fis')
and this is the FIS I created;
[System]
Name='Dc-Motor'
Type='mamdani'
Version=1.0
NumInputs=2
NumOutputs=1
NumRules=25
AndMethod='min'
OrMethod='max'
ImpMethod='min'
AggMethod='max'
DefuzzMethod='centroid'

[Input1]
Name= 'Error'
Range= [-97.5 +97.5 ]
NumMFs = 5
MF1='Nl':'trapmf',[=-67-66 -65 -32.5 ]
MF2='Ns':'trimf',[-65 -32.5 0 ]
MF3 ='Z':'trimf',[-32.5  0  32.5]
MF4 ='Ps':'trimf',[0  32.5  65]
MF5 ='Pl':'trapmf',[32.5 65 66 67]

[Input2]
Name ='Edot'
Range=[-54 54]
NumMFs=5
MF1='Nl':'trapmf',[-38-37 -36 -18]
MF2='Ns':'trimf',[-36 18  0]
MF3 ='Z':'trimf',[-18  0  18]
MF4 ='Ps':'trimf',[0  18  36]
MF5 ='Pl':'trapmf',[18 36  37 38]


[Output1]
Name ='U'
Range=[-155 155]
NumMFs=5
MF1='Nl':'trimf',[-155 -103.3  -51.66]
MF2='Ns':'trimf',[-103.3 -51.66  0]
MF3 ='Z':'trimf',[ -51.66  0   51.6 ]
MF4 ='Ps':'trimf',[ 0  51.66  103.3]
MF5 ='Pl':'trimf',[ 51.6  103.3  155]


[Rules]
1 1, 1 (1): 1
1 2, 1 (1): 1
1 3, 1 (1): 1
1 4, 1 (1): 1
1 5, 5 (1): 1
2 1, 1 (1): 1
2 2, 2 (1): 1
2 3, 2 (1): 1
2 4, 3 (1): 1
2 5, 2 (1): 1
3 1, 5 (1): 1
3 2, 4 (1): 1
3 3, 3 (1): 1
3 4, 2 (1): 1
3 5, 1 (1): 1
4 1, 1 (1): 1
4 2, 3 (1): 1
4 3, 4 (1): 1
4 4, 4 (1): 1
4 5, 5 (1): 1
5 1, 3 (1): 1
5 2, 4 (1): 1
5 3, 5 (1): 1
5 4, 4 (1): 1
5 5, 5 (1): 1


Above is what I tryied and I would need some answer to the question where in my PC hardrive I can find the code that generated those errors.

The cause of the error is that readFis expects rules to have a space between ) and :, so a readable rule would look like 1 1, 1 (1) : 1. From the source, the line_vec = ostrsplit (line, ",():", true) is expected to have five items: antecedent is line_vec{1}, consequent line_vec{2}, weight line_vec{3} and connection is line_vec{5}. AFAIK this is not in .fis specs, so it should be considered a bug.
